# How to get text from .InnerHTML to fade-in and fade-out when it changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I have a script that is simply changing text on my HTML page. It's text of "testimonials" that are set to change every 8 seconds. The script itself works fine but I am unable to get the text to fade-in when it changes again. You can see from my code that I'm able to get it to fade-in but it only does it on the very first time which is actually hard-coded into the code.

I've seen people post about how to change when you hover or click on something, but not when it's text being changed from a script.

Thanks in advance for helping out a newbie! :-)

```js
    const testimonials = [
      {
        name: "Robert - Louisville, KY",
        quote:
          '"I\'m not one to do readings but I actualy enjoyed the experience. Learning about the past, present, and future of my career was not only entertaining but insightful."',
      },
      {
        name: "Tyler - Louisville, KY",
        quote:
          '"It helped me gain some closure and realize that I can\'t just sit here and let life work itself out. I have to take my own initiative."',
      },
      {
        name: "Jason & Joey - Tampa, FL",
        quote:
          '"Kevin’s reading was spot-on! We went into it just for fun, without any expectations, and found ourselves nodding in agreement with everything he said. He was thorough in his explanations and made sure we understood exactly what the cards meant. We highly recommend a reading by Kevin."',
      },
    ];
    
    let counter = 0;
    const testimonialQuote = document.getElementById("newQuote");
    const testimonialName = document.getElementById("newName");
    const changeTime = setInterval(newTestimonial, 8000);
    
    function newTestimonial() {
      console.log("Starting function");
      testimonialQuote.innerHTML = Object.values(testimonials[counter])[1];
      testimonialName.innerHTML = Object.values(testimonials[counter])[0];
      counter++;
      if (counter >= testimonials.length) {
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
```

```css
    .quote-name-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    
    .testimonial-container #newQuote {
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      line-height: 2.2rem;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .testimonial-container #newName {
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      line-height: 2.2rem;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="testimonial-container">
            <h2 class="testimonial-header">Testimonials</h2>
            <div class="quote-name-container">
              <div id="newQuote">
                <!-- This is where the quote for the testimonial will go -->
                <p>"I'm not one to do readings but I actualy enjoyed the experience. Learning about the past, present, and future of my career was not only entertaining but insightful."'</p>
                <p>Robert - Louisville, KY</p>
              </div>
              <div id="newName">
                <!-- This is where the name for the quote will go -->
              </div>
              <script src="changetestimonial.js"></script>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: For this, you shouldn't use a CSS animation because that just runs on the quote container once. You could make it fade in and out, but it wouldn't be synched with the changing of the quote. Instead, you should set up a CSS transition on `opacity` and then in the JavaScript, change the opacity each time you change the quote.

Comment: Thanks. Everything I'm finding on CSS transitions (even looking through MDN) keeps showing how to do things with :hover. I don't want to only change the opacity from 0 to 1 and the back to 0 with a hover state. I want it to be able to do that on it's own until the next item is sent from JavaScript. Then it should repeat.

I do see in JavaScript I can set opacity with .style.opacity = 1; but if I start the opacity at 0, it doesn't do anything when it gets sent back through.

Anywhere else you can point me to see documentation about it?